# Trying to filter my list and push to the view MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a list of type AdListing
in my home controller I would like to push different filters of this list depending on a query string.

if `query == 1`, push the unfiltered full list

if `query == 2`, i would like to push the list where type == "cover" and numpage is over 5

```
return View(listing.Where(o => String.Equals(o.type, 
                                             "Cover", 
                                             StringComparison.InvariantCulture) 
                          && o.numPage > 5));
```

However I get an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[Project.Web.Models.AdListing]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'Project.Web.Models.AdViewModel'.

is there any way to resolve this without changing my viewModel or my AdListing Object?

Comment: Which is the type of the view?

Comment: I mean, the model of the view, or the View<T> type

Comment: the ViewModel uses List<AdList>

Answer (score 1):

Okay, firstly, it looks like you're trying to pass a list of objects to a view that's expecting a single object. Change your view to expect an `IEnumerable<AdListing>` model.

Now, as for your request, it should be as simple as:

```
if (query == 1)
{
    return View(listing);
}
else
{
    return View(listing.Where(o => String.Equals(o.type, "Cover", 
                                   StringComparison.InvariantCulture) 
                                   && o.numPage > 5).ToList());
}
```